# Download de package usando "go get"

Tags: golang

A instalação do `go` em `/usr/local/go` ocorre perfeitamente e posso verificar isto utilizando:

`go --version`

Ao tentar utilizar `get` com:

`go get github.com/russross/blackfriday`

recebo o seguinte erro:

> package github.com/russross/blackfriday: mkdir /usr/local/go/bin/go: not a directory

Detro de `use/local/go/bin/...` o `go` é na verdade o arquivo que executa a linguagem por este motivo não consigo criar uma pasta neste mesmo caminho.

**retorno de `go env`**

```
GOARCH="386"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="386"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/usr/local/go/bin/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_386"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GO386="sse2"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m32 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build009583842=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
```

Comment: Ja chegou a ver essa pergunta no SOen ? parece o mesmo problema  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846914/go-install-always-attempts-to-use-goroot-and-gopath-is-not-listed-under-go-env

Comment: a pergunta no`SOen` esta com um erro diferente ao que citei, mesmo que eu aplique a solução proposta no post recebo o erro `GOPATH entry is relative; must be absolute path: "".`

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o problema seja a sua variável de ambiente `GOPATH`, a `GOROOT` parece estar certa.

Você deve apontar a variável para o diretório que você deseja que seja o seu workspace.

Aqui, por exemplo, está configurado assim:

```
$ go env
GOARCH="386"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="386"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/admin/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_386"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GO386=""
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m32 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build890319421=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
```

A variável de ambiente `GOROOT` aponta para os arquivos da instalação:

```
$ ls -la $GOROOT
total 168
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root   4096 May 24 18:16 .
drwxrwsr-x 11 root staff  4096 May 30 10:48 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 May 24 18:15 api
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  33243 May 24 18:15 AUTHORS
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Aug  8 09:36 bin
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4096 May 24 18:16 blog
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   1366 May 24 18:15 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  45710 May 24 18:15 CONTRIBUTORS
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root   4096 May 24 18:15 doc
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   5686 May 24 18:15 favicon.ico
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 May 24 18:15 lib
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   1479 May 24 18:15 LICENSE
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root   4096 May 24 18:16 misc
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   1303 May 24 18:15 PATENTS
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root   4096 May 24 18:16 pkg
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   1399 May 24 18:15 README.md
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     26 May 24 18:15 robots.txt
drwxr-xr-x 46 root root   4096 May 24 18:15 src
drwxr-xr-x 17 root root  12288 May 24 18:15 test
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      7 May 24 18:15 VERSION
```

E a variável de ambiente `GOPATH` aponta para onde está o meu workspace:

```
$ ls -la $GOPATH
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 admin admin 4096 Aug  7 20:10 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 admin admin 4096 Sep 15 07:00 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 admin admin 4096 Aug 16 02:11 bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 admin admin 4096 Aug  7 20:10 pkg
drwxr-xr-x 8 admin admin 4096 Aug  7 21:55 src
```

Basta criar a pasta `src` e colocar seu código fonte lá dentro, o restante das pastas normalmente são criadas conforme você vai compilando código com o `go build`.